# Firebase.database().ref("RefNode").set(null) triggers OnDataChanged of that reference

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have **nodejs server** and an **android client**. Both are connected to my **firebase database**. When the server sets the **`"RefNode"`** to `null`, the `onDataChanged` Callback, that is set on that **`"RefNode"`** on the andriod side, gets called.

Is there any way to **avoid** it being called in the special case when the "RefNode" was set to null while for all other cases it should get called.

I have a listener on a node **`"RefNode"`** in my android application as given below:
The OnDataChanged() callback is getting called even when the **`"RefNode"`** was set to `null` by the nodejs server.

```
FirbaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("RefNode").addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                if(dataSnapshot.getValue()!=null) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "got here even when the Refnode was set to null");
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // The listener got cancelled
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem I had attached the event listener twice. I had made the ValueEventListener a field of the class the and attached it twice.